# React image mapper override highlight for certain areas

Tags: reactjs, imagemap, react-image

I am using the npm package react-image-mapper to map certain areas on a hotel floor plan image. Now I want to add a permanent red highlight on the rooms that are already booked and highlight other rooms with a different color on hover.

The react-image-mapper has the option to change the fillColor prop of the component. But it changes for all the areas. I want to change it for certain areas only. Is there a way to achieve this in react-image-mapper?

Comment: try https://github.com/NishargShah/react-img-mapper

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [this](https://github.com/coldiary/react-image-mapper) library? If yes, then update it and you will have flexibility to change particular areas. If you do not find it then try downloading the library from [this](https://github.com/skumar495/react-image-mapper) link.